# How to expand the drop menu?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make "https://www.uscreen.tv/contact-us/", "what you get" on the site in this link.

I tried to do it as you see in the codes, but there are some problem. I want this part to go down from the top. I couldn't figure out how it was done. I've tried these in my codes below. Thanks

```
    <div class="header">
      <div class="list">
        <div class="header-list">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-menu">
              <a href="">What You Get</a>
              <ul class="menu-area">
               
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

```
    .header .list .header-list .dropdown-menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .header .list .header-list .dropdown-menu img {
      background: rgb(80, 77, 77);
    }

    .header .list .header-list>li.dropdown-menu>a::after {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
    }

    .header .list .header-list .menu-area {
      background: #181A1B;
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      width: 1172px; /* I don't understand if this is looking for a job. */
      top: -9999px;
      left: 0;
      height: 550px;
    }

    .header .list .header-list ul li:hover ul.menu-area {
      top: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).